# Iterate over values in an object in Lua (by order)

Tags: lua

I am looking for a simple solution for my problem. I've got this code:

```
local Month = {
    Jan = 1, Feb = 2, Mar = 3, Apr = 4,
    May = 5, Jun = 6, Jul = 7, Aug = 8,
    Sep = 9, Oct = 10, Nov = 11, Dec = 12
}
...
p.main = function()
    local text = ""
    for k,v in pairs(Month) do
        text = text .. " " .. k;
    end
    return text;
end
```

When I call `p.main()` I would like it to print `Jan Feb ... Dec` (in order) though it prints `Jan Mar Apr Oct Feb Dec Nov Aug Jul May Jun Sep` which seems to me quite a random order.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hash part of tables in Lua is *unordered*. String keys go in the hash part. This is why you're observing the "random" order.

Simply convert your `Month` table from a mapping from month names to numbers to a mapping from numbers to names, i.e. flip it and convert it to a list:

```lua
local monthnames = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}
```

then you can conveniently iterate it in order using `ipairs` (rather than `pairs`) - even more, your `p.main` function simplifies to a single call to `table.concat`, a Lua built-in function for concatenating a list of strings, and since the value is constant, you can pre-calculate it:

```lua
local space_separated_monthnames = table.concat(monthnames, " ")
function p.main()
    return space_separated_monthnames
end
```

This won't add a leading space, but I don't think that's intended anyways.

If you need to keep the old lookup, no problem - you can generate it from the list:

```lua
local monthnumber = {}
for i, name in ipairs(monthnames) do
    monthnumber[name] = i
end
```

Also note that string concatenation in a loop is an antipattern in Lua since it is both inefficient (quadratic vs. linear, very noticeable if you're building longer strings at least) and inconvenient to write (e.g. your code emits a probably unwanted leading space and more code would be required to not emit it). In general, if you see something like:

```lua
local str = vals[1]
for i = 2, #vals do
    str = str .. separator .. vals[i]
end
```

refactor it to

```lua
local str = table.concat(vals, separator)
```

both for performance and readability.